# Get img src value inside a document.write PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I need to get the image src value from the following code using PHP XPath & node.

Sample HTML

```
<div class=\"thumb-inside\">
   <div class=\"thumb\">
      <script>document.write(thumbs.replaceThumbUrl('<a href=\"....."><img src=\".....\" /></a>'));</script>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried like this:

```
$node = $xpath->query("div[@class='thumb-inside']/div[@class='thumb'‌​]/a/img/attribute::s‌​rc", $e);
$th = $node->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: $node = $xpath->query("div[@class='thumb-inside']/div[@class='thumb']/a/img/attribute::src", $e);
  $th = $node->item(0)->nodeValue;

Comment: I tied like this

Comment: It seems the `a` element you need is part from the text of a `script`, I think you can try to get the text from the script, `explode` by `"` and get the part you need, the second I think.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved through the following code. But I dont know whether its a correct code.

```
        $string = str_replace("document.write(thumbs.replaceThumbUrl(","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("'));","",$string);
    $pattern = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $th = $matches[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMDocument` in php like below to get the image source.

```
    $html=file_get_contents('file_path');

    $doc = new \DomDocument();      
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
```